# How to get a crawler to run n times, stop and wait 10 minutes, and then run it again n times and repeat the whole process?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, web-crawler

i have a web crawler:

```
import http.client
import time
import threading

class Worker(threading.Thread):                            # Booting crawler workers
    def __init__(self, base, ref, conn, urlKey, url):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.base = base
        self.ref = ref
        self.conn = conn
        self.urlKey = urlKey
        self.url = url
        
    def run_aux(self):                                     # Getting web response and do stuff with it
        self.conn.request('GET', self.url)
        response = self.conn.getresponse()
        status = response.status
        if status == 200:
            data = str(response.read())
           
            if data.find('No he podido entenderte.') != -1:
                data = 'Err: Ruta no comprendida'
            else:
                pos = data.find('>Id: ') + 5
                if pos == 4:
                    data = 'Err: Tag >Id: no encontrado'
                else:
                    data = data[pos:pos+32]  
        else:
            data = 'Err: ' + str(status)
        response.close()
        self.base.saveRes(self.urlKey, data, self.ref)
        
    def run(self):          # Auxiliary function that allows the crawler to  continue running if any problem is found while connecting to the web site. It will continue trying to runtill connections are accepted
        try:
            self.run_aux()
        except Exception as e:
            self.run()

class MIdCrawler(object):                               # Boot and instantiate the crawler
    def __init__(self, site, nThreads, urlDict):
        self.res = {}
        self.nThreads = nThreads
        self.urlDict = urlDict.copy()
        self.urlKeys = list(self.urlDict.keys())
        self.conns = [http.client.HTTPSConnection(site) for _ in range(self.nThreads)]
        self.threads_launched = 0
        self.launch()

    def newThread(self, ref):          # How the threads are launched
        if self.threads_launched < len(self.urlKeys):
            urlKey = self.urlKeys[self.threads_launched]
            Worker(self, ref, self.conns[ref], urlKey, self.urlDict.get(urlKey)).start()
            self.threads_launched += 1

    def launch(self):                       # Create new threads
        for i in range(self.nThreads):
            self.newThread(i)
            
    def saveRes(self, urlKey, data, ref):           # Saving the results into a dict
        self.res[urlKey] = data
        #print('Dato guardado')
        print(urlKey)
        self.newThread(ref)
    
    def getRes(self):                                      # Return results
        while len(self.res) < len(self.urlKeys):
            time.sleep(0.5)
        return(self.res)

    def close(self):                          # Close working threads
        for i in range(self.nThreads):
            self.conns[i].close()
```

this crawler will recover certain data from a web server of mine, when my server receives the call, it will call the Google Maps api in order to recover some route data. I have to make like 3000 calls, the problem is that i noticed that Google Maps stops answering calls when a certain number of consecutive calls are made from the same ip in a short period of time. There is a not a fix number of calls for this red flag to appear but it is always between the 240 and 300 consecutive calls.

This crawler allows to specify the number of threads (calls) that we want to boot in parallel, the problem is that when i get to the 2xx-300 calls the Google Maps server stops answering my petitions.

I'm new to this web scraping thing and i would like someone to tell me how can i modify this crawler to run 200 calls, wait ten minutes, and then continue from the point where it stopped.

This is some example data that the crawler receives:

```
['/testchat?text=quiero%20ir%20desde%20carrer%20cervantes%2C%201%2C%20sant%20andreu%20de%20la%20barca%2C%20hasta%20avinguda%20constituci%C3%B3%2C%2024%2C%20sant%20andreu%20de%20la%20barca',
 '/testchat?text=quiero%20ir%20desde%20General%20Mitre%20239%2C%20Barcelona%2C%20hasta%20Plaza%20Artos%2C%20Barcelona',
 '/testchat?text=quiero%20ir%20desde%20carrer%20Bon%20viatge%2C%20sant%20Joan%20Desp%C3%AD%2C%20hasta%20mare%20de%20deu%20la%20Merc%C3%A8%2C%20sant%20Joan%20Desp%C3%AD',
 '/testchat?text=quiero%20ir%20desde%20no%20recuerdo%2C%20hasta%20no%20recuerdo',
 '/testchat?text=quiero%20ir%20desde%20travessera%20de%20les%20corts%2C%20barcelona%2C%20hasta%20Avenida%20diagonal%2050%2C%20barcelona',
 '/testchat?text=quiero%20ir%20desde%20Confidencial%2C%20hasta%20Confdencial%2C%20Confidencial',
 '/testchat?text=quiero%20ir%20desde%20Paseo%20Zona%20Franca%20241%2C%20Barcelona%2C%20hasta%20Plaza%20Espa%C3%B1a%2C%20Barcelona',
 '/testchat?text=quiero%20ir%20desde%20Rbla.%20les%20bobiles%2014%2C%20martorell%2C%20hasta%20plaza%20de%20la%20vila%201%2C%20martorell',
 '/testchat?text=quiero%20ir%20desde%20Rambla%20de%20Catalu%C3%B1a%2086%2C%20Barcelona%2C%20hasta%20Padilla%20342%2C%20Barcelona',
 '/testchat?text=quiero%20ir%20desde%20Concepci%C3%B3n%2C%20Abrera%2C%20hasta%20Major%2C%20Abrera']
```

An example call to the crawler:

```
site = 'sema-dev-backend.mybluemix.net'

urlDict = df.url.reset_index(drop = True).to_dict()

nThreads = 5

ts1 = time.time()

mIdCrawler = MIdCrawler(site, nThreads, urlDict)
print(mIdCrawler.getRes())

t = time.time() - ts1

print('secs: ' + str(t))
print('mean_time: ' + str(t / len(urlDict)))
```

What should i modify in this code to do it make 200 calls to my web service, stop and wait 10 minutes, and then later, continue where it stopped for again 200 calls and repeat the process?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a main() function, which i create using the code you provided:

```py
def main()
    site = 'sema-dev-backend.mybluemix.net'
    urlDict = df.url.reset_index(drop = True).to_dict()
    nThreads = 5
    ts1 = time.time()
    mIdCrawler = MIdCrawler(site, nThreads, urlDict)
    print(mIdCrawler.getRes())
    t = time.time() - ts1
    print('secs: ' + str(t))
    print('mean_time: ' + str(t / len(urlDict)))
```

Then you can use this loop:

```py
import time
try:
    while True:
        for i in range(0, 200): #execute 200 times
            main()
        time.sleep(60*10) #10 minute delay
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("stopping script")
    exit(0)
```